# SQLite or coredata or other

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

This is for an iphone app. What's the best route that I should take? I have data and I would like to have it in my app and access it throughout the app in different ways search, title, state, etc.

I don't want the user to be able to modify it or delete it.

Should I use core data or SQLite or is there a better way?

Thank you

Comment: What sort of data and how often will it be accessed?

Comment: The app allows you to view the local laws by state or location etc so provably accessed pretty often.   I was thinking about storing the laws in a database flat file.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would recommend using CoreData for its ease of use. CoreData, in fact, act as an abstraction layer over SQLite so, you don't need to actually write any SQL lines.

Take a look at the CoreData documentation from Apple so you can understand exactly what it is. Or, maybe, you can jump to their Tutorial for a "hands-on" explaining:

[Core Data Tutorial for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Also, I personally like to use tutorials from the Ray Wenderlich sites, like this one:

[Core Data on iOS 5 Tutorial: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started)

(by the time of writing this, the Ray Wenderlich's site is under maintenance.. but check it out later.. it is pretty good!)